# How do I find all files that do NOT have SYSTEM permission?

Tags: windows-8, acl, icacls

I saw that I can use `icacls` to find all files matching a SID, but how do I find all files that DO NOT have access for SYSTEM user?

```
ICACLS name /findsid Sid [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    finds all matching names that contain an ACL
    explicitly mentioning Sid.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done a lot of testing, but the following PowerShell script should work:

```
param([string]$path)

get-childitem $path -recurse | Foreach {
    $file=$_;get-acl $($_.FullName)} | Foreach {

    [bool]$SystemHasAccess = $false

    $_.GetAccessRules($True,$True,[Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) | Foreach {
        if ($_.IdentityReference -eq "S-1-5-18") { $SystemHasAccess = $true }  # system sid
        if ($_.IdentityReference -eq "S-1-1-0") { $SystemHasAccess = $true }   # everyone sid                    
    }

    if ($SystemHasAccess -eq $false)
    {
       write-host "System has no access to $($file.FullName)"
    }
}
```

copy the code into a file, say "FindFilesWithoutSystemAccess.ps1", then call it by supplying the path you want to search:

```
FindFilesWithoutSystemAccess.ps1 -path C:\
```

The script loops through all files under the path including any files in sub-directories. 
For each file it loops through all access control entries in the file's access control list. If none of them match the internal sid of system (S-1-5-18) it prints out the full name of the file.

It is possible that a file has an ACE for System, but it is a deny ACE, which means the script above doesn't catch the file and System still can't access it. However the scenario is unlikely and you could use a similar script to find such files.

Comment: I ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process` and `.\FindFilesWithoutSystemAccess.ps1 -path C:\cygwin\home\Chloe` and it gave this error: `.\FindFilesWithoutSystemAccess.ps1 : Access to the path 'C:\cygwin\home\Chloe\FindFilesWithoutSystemAccess.ps1' is
denied.
At line:1 char:1`

Comment: That is SO strange! Whenever I save a file with .ps1 extension, it removes my user permissions! I can create a `tmp.ps1` in a text editor, and save it once, but no more! I have to go and modify file properties in Explorer to read/write it again!

Comment: I got many `get-childitem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than
260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.` errors.

Comment: It dies at `get-acl : The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: Purple Motion - Unreal ][.s3m
At C:\cygwin\home\Chloe\FindFilesWithoutSystemAccess.ps1:4 char:14
+     $file=$_;get-acl "$($_.FullName)"} `. I tried to add quotes, but it didn't help.

Comment: Some of the files have EVERYONE read permissions. Doesn't that mean SYSTEM can read them too? `icacls C:\Users\Chloe\Downloads\setup.log` returns `C:\Users\Chloe\Downloads\setup.log xps\Chloe:(R,W,D,WDAC,WO)
                                   xps\None:(R)
                                   Everyone:(R)`

Comment: @Chloe - You are right, I added a check for the everyone ace

Comment: @Chloe - There are indeed problems with this script if you have a very long path (>260), or if the file-name has an opening square bracket without a matching closing one. Ideally you want to avoid such names. Another script could find such files, but that should be a different question. It may also be possible to add error handling to this script and make it work.

Comment: (It also finds for directories that don’t have `SYSTEM` permissions.)